# Detect end of line before next one

Tags: c++, stream

I don't know how to "buffer" a line of input (and perform some operations on that line, e.g. insert a newline at the end) before the next one in the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Test {
  public:
    template<class T>
    Test& operator<< (T&& anything) {
        std::cout << anything;
        return *this;
    }

};

int main() {
    Test myobj;

    myobj << "hello" << "this is cool";
    // How to insert a newline here?        
    myobj << "but" << "this is NOT cool";
}
```

I'd like to be able to detect when the line

```
myobj << "hello" << "this is cool";
```

has completed before the next one is executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can detect it in its destructor. Create a `log()` helper function that returns a temporary. At the end of the full expression its destructor will run:

```
class Test {
public:
    template<class T>
    Test& operator<< (T&& anything) {...}

    ~Test() { std::cout << std::endl; }
};

Test log() { return Test(); }
// ...
log() << "hello" << "this is cool";   // destructor inserts a newline here
log() << "but" << "this is NOT cool"; // here too
```

Answer (score 1):

```
`"\n"`
```

do it for you as shown below:

```
int main() {
    Test myobj;

    myobj<< "hello" << "this is cool<<"\n"";
    // How to insert a newline here?        
   myobj << "but" << "this is NOT cool";
}
```

Or otherwise you use `std::endl` as follows

```
myobj << "hello" << "this is cool<<std::endl;
```

Comment: I wrote "perform some operations" because I need to do something more complex than adding a simple newline. Frankly I'd prefer not to use a "terminator" object. I will if I'm forced to.

Comment: @Albert Are you looking for std::stringbuffer?

Comment: Not really, the objects I'll be receiving are complex ones (not always convertible to simple strings) and I need to buffer them for an 'entire line' of input before start using them.